# Routing with a Cisco 3750

Tags: routing

I have some machines and a hub :

2 PC 192.168.1.x/24

2 PC 192.168.2.x/24

2 PC 192.168.3.x/24

1 PC with 3 nic 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.3.1, this PC is running Windows server following [this tutorial](https://msftwebcast.com/2020/02/configure-lan-routing-in-windows-server-2019.html)

All machines are directly connected to the hub and all PC can ping all PC, even if they are not in the same network thanks to the PC with 3 nic.

I have a Cisco 3750 and I wonder if I can replace the hub with it and enable some routing. With that, I want to remove the 3 nic PC working as a router.
Is that doable with a Cisco 3750? And how?

The running OS is 12.2(55)SE.

Please note that I have low knowledge in networking and this is not the exact machines' configuration. I simplified to be easy.

Comment: This looks very much like homework. In short, you need to pull ports from switching with "no switchport" and assign appropriate IPs to them, or make VLANs, assign untagged VLAN IDs to respective ports and assign appropriate IPs to VLAN virtual interfaces.

Comment: It's not an homework, it's just that I never use a cisco hardware before. Are the steps you describe enough? The is no need to active some routing protocol?

Comment: Routing protocol is needed to dynamically configure routes through communication with other routers. As you are going to configure static routing, there is no need to configure any dynamic routing protocols. Also I'm sorry for not giving a full blown exact answer; currently I don't have any Cisco switch at my disposal to check before sharing.

Comment: It's all good, there is only one network device so it should work :) ty !